# Bad practice to set layout to null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-layout

Is it bad practice to set the layout of an MVC view to `null`?

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
// Some Content
</body>
</html>
```

By 'bad practice', I mean is anybody aware of inner-components of the MVC rendering engine that depend on a layout to be an instance of an object? Or is this a fine approach to specifying 'no layout'?

### **To Confirm**

This approach works and gives me the result I'm after, I'm asking whether I could inadvertently cause headaches elsewhere in the system.

Apologies, I should've clarified - I am leveraging _ViewStart to set the layout, so this serves as an override (probably missed a key bit of the question out there sorry!)

Comment: how about removing @{
    Layout = null;
} if you don't want a layout?

Comment: Remove the code `@{Layout = null;}` as suggested by @Lidaranis. It is not required.

Comment: Setting the Layout explicitly to null might be necessary if you want to get rid of a standard layout defined in _ViewStart.cshtml. For example, if you want to render dialog contents using a parital view and they should not show the default menu.

Answer (score 6):

I just created a new CSHTML view page (without a layout) and this was at the top:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

NULL means don't use a layout.  So no, not bad practice and should have no consequence.